# Convert Locale Date to Date Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to convert *locale* date to date object. What is correct way to do so?

Check out the code below:

```js
> new Date() 
2020-05-19T09:43:17.154Z // UTC Date

> new Date().toLocaleString() 
'5/19/2020, 12:43:27 PM' // Locale Date

> new Date(new Date().toLocaleString())
2020-05-19T09:43:33.000Z // UTC Date again
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no "locale Date" objects. The Date object stores milliseconds since The Epoch (midnight January 1st, 1970). It's just that depending on what method you call on the `Date` object, it reports the date information you ask for in UTC or in local time.

For instance, `getMonth` gives you the current month in local time. `getUTCMonth` gives you the current month in UTC:

```js
let dt;

// Example: Midnight May 15th 2020 UTC
dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 4, 15));
console.log(dt.getUTCDate()); // Always 15
console.log(dt.getDate());    // If you're in GMT or GMT+x, 15
                              // but if you're in GMT-, it'll be 14
                              
// Example: Midnight *local time* May 15th 2020
dt = new Date(2020, 4, 15);
console.log(dt.getUTCDate()); // 14 if you're in GMT+x
console.log(dt.getDate());    // Always 15
```

(Also on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/9na71txq/), since Stack Snippets are down right now for a lot of people.)

So there aren't different objects to convert between. There's a single object, that holds a single piece of information, that it reports differently depending on whether you ask it for information in the local timezone or UTC.

Comment: Thanks! So I will need to pass new Date locale parameters to get desired date object, rigth? Like so `new Date(year, month[, day[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]])`

Comment: @SystemsRebooter - Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking there.